# Returning a value from a specific column for a matched value in an array

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I have two columns that are a zip code and a corresponding district. Since most of the time zip codes are easy to find but districts are not, I'd like to create a column that updates districts based on what zip code is entered. Can you help me create an INDEX MATCH formula to do this?

Attached is an example worksheet but here are some images of my set up.

[image]

[image]

The goal is to the have the district column update based on the zip code entered. The data for which zip code corresponds to its respective district are presented in the second picture (not fully completed).

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Kyle, it might be easier to put the zipcodes and districts in one table with two columns: zipcode | districts and then use a vlookup or index match on these columns

Answer (score 0):

If one zip code cannot be in more than one district, you can use the `SUMPRODUCT` function:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($D$2:$J$6=B2)*$D$1:$J$1)
```

If it can be (as in your example with `80249`), then `INDEX` / `AGGREGATE`:

```
=INDEX($D$1:$J$1,1,AGGREGATE(15,6,(1/(B2=$D$2:$J$5))*COLUMN($D$1:$J$1)-3,1))
```

[image]